# Adding a pseudo style from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Am having a trouble with following code. The problem when adding the following style from jquery.

**CSS**

```
  .arrow_box {
position: absolute;
width: 24px;
border-radius: 30px 30px 3px 3px;
height: 17px;
float:left;
 }
.arrow_box:after {
border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
border-top-color: #88b7d5;
border-width: 14px;
left: 0%;
 }
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.arrow_box:after').css({
        "border-color": "red",
            "border-top-color": " #88b7d5",
            "border-width": "12px",
            "left": "0%"
    });
});
</script>
```

There will not have any jquery error but it is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after/5335771 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095177/jquery-using-after-selector. It would have benefited had you yourself looked this up.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly do this with jquery. But here solution with pure javascript http://www.4pmp.com/2009/11/dynamic-css-pseudo-class-styles-with-jquery/

Comment: The link is broken. I found this: https://web.archive.org/web/20170616025900/http://www.4pmp.com/2009/11/dynamic-css-pseudo-class-styles-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements are not DOM elements targetable with JavaScript.

Comment: is there a way to add this dynamically.?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements are not DOM elements so you can not access them using JavaScript or jQuery.