# Modifying css class with nth-child and :after pseudo using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element, css-selectors

Is there any way to modify the css of nth-child with after pseudo?

```
 $(".product-block:nth-child(-n+6):after").css("background-color", "#" + col6);
```

The css of the element results in the black tab as you can see below (to the first six items), I'm making a theme switcher which is why I'm needing to do this.

[image: Result of the element above]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095177/jquery-using-after-selector

Comment: Maybe a better one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: first one might be a bit of an overkill, second link has some good methods +1'd :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use .next();

$(".product-block:nth-child(-n+6)").next().css("background-color", "#" + col6);